# Python type annotation for list of potential return values

Tags: python, python-3.x, annotations, type-hinting, python-typing

Can a Python function be annotated with a list of potential return values?

```py
RAINY = 'rainy'
SUNNY = 'sunny'
CLOUDY = 'cloudy'
SNOWY = 'snowy'
TYPES_OF_WEATHER = [RAINY, SUNNY, CLOUDY, SNOWY]

def today_is_probably(season) -> OneOf[TYPES_OF_WEATHER]:
  if season is 'spring':
    return RAINY
  if season is 'summer':
    return SUNNY
  if season is 'autumn':
    return CLOUDY
  if season is 'winter':
    return SNOWY
```

Answer (score 4):

The [`Literal`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Literal) type seems to be what you are looking for here:

```python
from typing import Literal

def today_is_probably(season) -> Literal[RAINY, SUNNY, CLOUDY, SNOWY]:
    ...
```

You may also consider defining an [`enum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html) and use it as the type. It seems to be the most appropriate way here

```python
import enum

class Weather(enum.Enum):
    RAINY = 'rainy'
    SUNNY = 'sunny'
    CLOUDY = 'cloudy'
    SNOWY = 'snowy'

def today_is_probably(season) -> Weather:
    ...
```